# ChartJS not showing data for time series bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This was working when it was a line chart, but I am trying to convert it to a bar chart. The X-axis displays properly with all of the separate date spans and it changes when I select a dataset. However, none of the data is being displayed on the Y-axis. What is the issue?

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('activityChart');
  var timeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';



  var StMarySchool = [{x: 1583422868000,y:1.5},{x: 1583510166000,y:1.5},{x: 1583516698000,y:0.75},{x: 1583516698000,y:0.75},{x: 1583568876000,y:3.75},{x: 1583575074000,y:0.75},{x: 1583581331000,y:1.875},{x: 1583585883000,y:1.875},{x: 1583664583000,y:0.375},{x: 1583664583000,y:0.375},{x: 1583693978000,y:1.875},{x: 1583749868000,y:0.75},{x: 1583756595000,y:0.75},{x: 1583789510000,y:0.75},{x: 1583837107000,y:1.125},{x: 1583852507000,y:0.75},{x: 1583852988000,y:0.75},{x: 1583872458000,y:1.875},{x: 1584121049000,y:1.5},{x: 1584172626000,y:3.75},{x: 1584445225000,y:0.75},{x: 1584533992000,y:3.75},{x: 1584538374000,y:1.125},{x: 1584538374000,y:1.125},{x: 1584565055000,y:1.125},{x: 1584783939000,y:1.875},{x: 1585034842000,y:1.875},{x: 1585073536000,y:1.875},{x: 1587468291000,y:0.75},{x: 1588780685000,y:1.875},{x: 1589222744000,y:0.75},{x: 1589560042000,y:1.125},{x: 1592056137000,y:1.875},{x: 1592144769000,y:0.75},{x: 1592299139000,y:0.75},{x: 1592816935000,y:0.75},{x: 1592900043000,y:0.75},{x: 1592909141000,y:7.5},{x: 1593162077000,y:1.125},{x: 1593961268000,y:1.875},{x: 1593961312000,y:1.875},{x: 1594487280000,y:1.875},{x: 1595336470000,y:0.75},{x: 1596191887000,y:0.75},{x: 1596785796000,y:3.75},{x: 1596989721000,y:1.5},{x: 1596989721000,y:1.5},{x: 1596989721000,y:1.5},{x: 1597007626000,y:0.75},{x: 1597139159000,y:0.75},{x: 1597184422000,y:0.75},{x: 1597322300000,y:0.75},{x: 1597341478000,y:1.125},{x: 1597431163000,y:1.5},{x: 1597666257000,y:0.75},{x: 1597857382000,y:1.875},{x: 1598288284000,y:0.75},{x: 1598462641000,y:0.75}];var BagelUniversity = [{x: 1596095822000,y:0.75},{x: 1596966501000,y:0.75},{x: 1597564562000,y:0.75},{x: 1597564562000,y:0.75},{x: 1597765250000,y:0.75},{x: 1598288284000,y:0.75}];var MerighisSavoyInn = [{x: 1597406165000,y:1.875},{x: 1597428169000,y:1.875},{x: 1597681599000,y:1.875}];



  var config = {
        type:    'bar',
        data:    {
            datasets: [
                {label:'Bagel University', data: BagelUniversity, fill: true, backgroundColor: ['rgba(239, 248, 251, .70)'],borderColor: ['rgb(42, 159, 216)']},{label:'Merighis Savoy Inn', data: MerighisSavoyInn, fill: true, backgroundColor: ['rgba(239, 248, 251, .70)'],borderColor: ['rgb(42, 159, 216)']},{label:'St. Mary School', data: StMarySchool, fill: true, backgroundColor: ['rgba(239, 248, 251, .70)'],borderColor: ['rgb(42, 159, 216)']}   
            ]
        },
        options: { 
            responsive: true,
            title:      {
                display: false
            },
            scales:     {
                xAxes: [{
                    offset: true,
                    type:     "time",
                    /*time:       {
                        unit: 'month',
                        format: timeFormat,
                        tooltipFormat: 'll',
                        max:"05/03/2020" ,
                        min:"26/08/2020",
                    },*/
                    time: {
                      unit: 'day',
                      round: 'day',
                      displayFormats: {
                        day: 'MMM D'
                      }
                    },

                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    },

                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: '$'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                }]
            },

        }
    };

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that every date has to be in the data, regardless if it contains a datapoint.